# fixing reading and writing csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

The code under the with `open()` function doesn't work. The `a.writerows()` function doesn't work it give an `error`. PLease can you help finsih my code.

```
filename = class_name + ".csv"
csv.register_dialect('pipes', delimiter='|')
with open('filename.csv', 'a',newline='') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
    data=[['Name','Score'],
          [name,score]]
    a.writerows()


if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
    with open('testdata.pipes', 'r') as f:
        reader =csv.reader(fp, dialec = 'pipes')
        for row in reader:
            print (data)
else:
    input ("Press any key to exit")
```

Comment: it doesn't except writerows()

Comment: You have to pass data to the writerows.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass an argument to `.writerows()`:

```
a.writerows(data)
```

Later on, in the second loop, you're also not referencing the correct variable. `print(data)` will always output the same content (defined above) instead of what's actually in the file. That line should be `print(row)`.